# Mysql database empty column values vs additional identifying table

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

Sorry, not sure if question title is reflects the real question, but here goes:
I designing system which have standard orders table but with additional previous and next columns.

The question is which approach for foreign keys is better

[image]

Here I have basic table with following columns (previous, next) which are self referencing foreign keys. The problem with this table is that the first placed order doesn't have previous and next fields, so they left out empty, so if I have say 10 000 records 30% of them have those columns empty that's 3000 rows which is quite a lot I think, and also I expect numbers to grow. so in a let's say a year time period it can come to 30000 rows with empty columns, and I am not sure if it's ok.

[image]

The solution I've have came with is to main table with other 2 tables which have foreign keys to that table. In this case those 2 additional tables are identifying tables and nothing more, and there's no longer rows with empty columns.

So the question is which solution is better when considering query speed, table optimization, and common good practices, or maybe there's one even better that I don't know? (P.s. I am using mysql with InnoDB engine).

Comment: First I have never seen this kind of table structure. You can get next and previous dynamically (using date_created or id if it is autoincrement) even if you don't have foreign key for them, that is what people do usually. second What is wrong with having empty columns?

Comment: The question is: why are you using these columns for? Do you intent to insert orders in between 2 existing orders, and update links?

Comment: @didierc, yes there will be other rows between 2 existing orders, I need I need reference it's correct next and previous matches.

Comment: I meant: do you intend to add new rows which will be inserted between existing rows so that their `next` and `prev` links will have to be updated? You could be simply adding new rows which would only update the `next` link of the previous row, ie appending to the list.

Comment: The second question is, if so, why? And how frequently will you be doing this?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question, let me correct my self, No the links will not change once they written to databse so if order with id 10, has previous order with id 7, and next order with id 14, they will stay same for good. I just wan't to avoid empty columns in my table, because there will be a lot of records which won't have previous and next columns. Of course  I could just enter same id when there's no next and previous something like id:1|previous:1|next:1 which would reference to it self with no foreign keys, or extra tables, but I think that it would put strain on the table.

Comment: But maybe I'am over thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to do order sets, you could simply add a new table for that, and just have a single column as a foreign key to that table in the order table.
The `orders` could also include a `rank` column to indicate in which order orders belonging to the same set come.

```
create table order_sets (
    id not null auto_increment,
    -- customer related data, etc...
    primary key(id)
);

create table orders (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar,
    quantity int,
    set_id foreign key (order_set),
    set_rank int,
    primary key(id)
);
```

Then inserting a new order means updating the rank of all other orders which come after in the same set, if any.

Likewise, for *grouping* queries, things are way easier than having to follow prev and next links. I'm pretty sure you will need these queries, and the performances will be much better that way.